# Getting properties with values from Entity with navigation

Tags: reflection, navigation, properties, entity

I have data entity class, let’s say Customers which also contains some other navigation properties, let’s say Orders which contains OrdersDetails and so on, it can be a lot of them in each system.

I know that I can get list all of the Customers properties using reflection and I can also consume them if I want’ to also by reflection like in sample code below.

```
MyData ctx = new MyData();
Dictionary<string, string> listap = new Dictionary<string, string>();

// first part – getting properties

var type = typeof(Customers);
var members = from c in type.GetProperties()  select c;
        foreach (var item in members)
        {               
            listap.Add(item.Name.ToString(), item.PropertyType.Name.ToString());
        }

// second part – getting properties values

var item2 = (from c in ctx.Customers select c);
foreach (var item3 in item2)
   {

        foreach (var item in listap)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Key + "  " + item.Value + "    " +
            (typeof(Customers).GetProperty(item.Key).GetValue(item3, null)).ToString());

        }          
    }
```

What I want to do is:

- First be able to get the properties of all other Entity classes connected to Customers through navigation even they are few levels away  - Orders and   OrderDetails in this case and be able to add them to listap dictionary.
- Get to properties values even if they are few level away from Customers using list of properties from first point.

I can get the properties concerning Orders from first part but I don’t know how to utilize them in second part and how to get one more level deeper to OrdersDetails.